# How to find the limit of irrotational flow past a finite plate?

Tags: calculus, limits, fluid-dynamics

In chapter 4 of Acheson's Fluid Dynamics we have the equation
$$u_*-iv_*=\left(Ue^{-i\alpha}-Ue^{i\alpha}\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}-\frac{i\Gamma}{2\pi (a+\varepsilon)}\right)\bigg/\left(1-\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}\right)$$
which is the same as
$$u_*-iv_*=\left(Ue^{-i\alpha}-Ue^{i\alpha}\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}+\frac{i4\pi Ua\sin\alpha}{2\pi (a+\varepsilon)}\right)\bigg/\left(1-\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}\right)$$
on account of value found for $\Gamma$. While for $\varepsilon=0$ both numerator and denominator vanish (necessary to remove the singularities), the author states that *as* $\varepsilon\to0$, $u_*$ goes to $U\cos\alpha$ while the imaginary part vanishes, and I don't see how he finds this.

Comment: @Gonçalo yes of course- just a typo. As I've written the numerator goes to zero when $\varepsilon=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple algebra. The real part of the numerator is
$$
U\cos\alpha-U\cos\alpha\,\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2} = 
U\cos\alpha\left(1-\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}\right),
$$
and its imaginary part is
\begin{align}
-U\sin\alpha-U\sin\alpha\,\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2} + 
\frac{2Ua\sin\alpha}{a+\varepsilon} &= 
-U\sin\alpha\left(1-\frac{2a}{a+\varepsilon}+\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}\right) \\
&=-U\sin\alpha\left(1-\frac{a}{a+\varepsilon}\right)^2.
\end{align}
Dividing by the denominator and taking the limit $\varepsilon\to 0$ we finally obtain
$$
u_* = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
\frac{U\cos\alpha\left(1-\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}\right)} = U\cos\alpha
$$
and
$$
v_* = -\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} 
\frac{U\sin\alpha\,\left(1-\frac{a}{a+\varepsilon}\right)^2}
{\left(1-\frac{a^2}{(a+\varepsilon)^2}\right)} =
-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} 
\frac{U\sin\alpha\left(1-\frac{a}{a+\varepsilon}\right)}
{\left(1+\frac{a}{a+\varepsilon}\right)} = 0. 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't see it. I was expanding the terms with $\varepsilon$ it but it was leading me nowhere.